# Does Shadow Banking (i.e. non-Commercial Banking) produce transaction-useful money?

Tags: monetary-policy, banking, shadow-banking

In shadow banking amongst primary dealers & large institutions...I understand repurchase agreements function similar to deposit accounts (Gorton, et al). Additionally, I understand how traditional commercial banking produces M1 in the form of deposits, etc.

My question is: Where is the analogous money being created by shadow banks? I.e. I cannot use a Repo agreement in a transaction, unlike how I can use deposit accounts in commercial banks. Intuitively I feel money is being created, but not in the *exact* transaction-useful form as traditional banking.

Is the "money" being created effectively by virtue that the collateral can be rehypothecaed?

To paraphrase Jerry Maguire...**Show me the transaction-useful money!**

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you talking about Fed repo operations as part of QE? In this case it's the fed producing the money and buying the security, but just allowing the bond to mature or otherwise ignoring the sell back (or reverse)

Comment: Hey, ya maybe I didn't give enough context. So, Commercial Banks produce short-term debt (deposit accounts) which add net NEW money to M1, correct? Repo functions VERY similarly, but for the non-commercial banks (i.e. 'Shadow Banks') -- So my question is: Is there net "new" money being created by Repo? And is re-hypothecation of collateral somehow related to this "new" money? (Re-hypo == Using your posted collateral for my own purposes)

Comment: Can you add a link to "Gorton, et al", or at least name the paper or define "transaction-useful money"? I get zero google hits for this term.

Comment: Also note that there's no standard definition for "M1" or all the M-terms for that matter. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broad_money

Comment: Well...1,000% precise definitions or not, it's clearly a colloquially useful framework to describe the "cash-likeness" of an asset. I feel like there is more than enough commonality to use the terms in an intellectual debate...

Comment: "Transaction-useful" I just used for shorthand. My point was: if un-conventional/shadow banking produces money (like its commercial counterpart), is it useful in transactions? I'm not sure MMF claims or Repo agreements are. But does that mean it's "less" money-like if can't be used directly in a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the ECB has given it [[re]consideration](https://www.bundesbank.de/resource/blob/622250/543c18dd179ac8882852fee86438909b/mL/2014-03-shadow-data.pdf)... by excluding repos from their M3 starting in August 2012.

> From a
>   monetary analysis perspective, it should be
>   checked, then, whether any of the liabilities issued
>   by the shadow banking system substitute
>   traditional bank deposits – that is, whether
>   they are comparable, say, with the bank deposits
>   included in M3 in terms of their degree
>   of liquidity and their risk characteristics.[footone: The extent to which these liabilities are used as money
>   substitutes is subject to cyclical fluctuations and dependent
>   on market developments.] If this
>   is the case, increasing shadow banking activity
>   would diminish the meaningfulness of monetary
>   indicators, with the monetary aggregates
>   needed for price determination in the goods
>   market, in particular, being defined too narrowly.
>   That is why, in an ever-evolving financial system,
>   it is crucial to regularly review the definitions
>   of monetary aggregates. At the launch of
>   EMU, the Eurosystem decided that the group
>   of monetary financial institutions (MFIs) designed
>   to capture the money-issuing sector
>   should include not just euro-area commercial
>   banks but money market funds as well, the
>   rationale
>   for this move being that for investors,
>   money market fund shares were close substitutes
>   for bank deposits in terms of liquidity and
>   therefore, much like bank deposits, were likely
>   to be related to spending decisions.
>   However, as monetary analysis is based on the
>   consolidated balance sheet of the MFI sector,
>   the concept of balance sheet identity dictates
>   that a corresponding counterpart must be
>   entered for each newly added monetary variable.
>   So if the Eurosystem adds the liabilities
>   side of money market funds’ balance sheets
>   – that is, the issued money market fund shares –
>   to the MFI sector’s consolidated balance sheet,
>   it follows that the assets side of money market
>   funds’ balance sheets likewise needs to be included.
>   This was relatively straightforward for
>   money market funds because they could be
>   subjected to reporting requirements and their
>   business activities essentially confined to receiving
>   and investing fund assets (the latter primarily
>   in short- term near-bank investments). [...]
>
> The increase in significance of the shadow
>   banking system goes hand in hand with greater
>   interaction between shadow banks and commercial
>   banks. While an unconsolidated analysis
>   of payment flows between the individual
>   financial
>   sector players is of interest from a
>   financial
>   stability perspective, monetary analysis
>   seeks to adjust the monetary and credit aggregates
>   affected by the interaction, if need be, so
>   as to best capture the changes relevant to price
>   developments.
>
> Repo and reverse repo transactions
>
> Secured money market transactions known as
>   repo and reverse repo transactions, which
>   commercial banks conclude with central counterparties
>   (such as Eurex Clearing AG, which
>   until recently was statistically classified as a
>   non- bank financial intermediary), are examples
>   of this. Repo transactions (reverse repo transactions transactions)
>   were originally presented in the banking
>   statistics – which are crucial for monetary
>   analysis – as an outflow (inflow) of funds for
>   the money- holding sector. **Yet for the most
>   part, these transactions inherently constitute
>   secured money market transactions between
>   commercial banks in which the central counterparty
>   merely acts as a go-between. Consequently,
>   the money supply is not expanded at
>   the macroeconomic level. These secured transactions
>   grew steadily in importance over the
>   course of the financial and economic crisis
>   owing to the high level of uncertainty in the
>   interbank market. They ultimately had such a
>   significant impact on short-term monetary and
>   credit developments, both in terms of quantity
>   and their month- on- month volatility (see the
>   chart on page 27), that the Eurosystem decided
>   to exclude them from the calculation of M3
>   and its counterparts in August 2012.**
>
> [image]

I don't know how the Fed deals with this. Like I said in a comment, the M-terms don't have universal definitions, when it comes to such details.

Note that the ECB has not excluded *all* the shadow banking from their M3 (not even all the repos), just the repos with "central counterparties".

> [image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for such a thorough answer. However, I don't understand the line, "Consequently, the money supply is not expanded at the macroeconomic level." -- How can that be? The lender is left with a deposit acct that affects their spending. And the borrower has actual cash. There is a new, cash-like liability being created?

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @Frank: it has to do with the context in which repos are [or aren't] included in the monetary indicators. I thought that what the questions is about. Of course, the question is vague as it doesn't define "transaction-useful money".

Comment: Yeah well no I understand the question to be 'does a repo transaction create money'

Comment: @DavisClute: I think what they mean by that is that when banks lend *to each other* via a repo arrangement (mediated by a 3rd party, which isn't even a bank), that doesn't increase the money that is lent to "mainstreet" businesses. This probably needs to be better documented with data; there's some wavelet analysis in that paper, but alas not on this issue, but on money markets having an effect on mainstreet.

Comment: @Fizz A bit confused, but was trying to follow your answer. So Repo increases the monetary supply (whether it's M3, etc) -- but it doesn't increase the amount of money in the "real" (mainstream) economy? Correct? If so, that seems like a weird (and hard to defend) distinction...

Comment: @DavisClute: I think they mean that it depends who's doing repo with whom. The ECB decided that banks doing repos with each other (via some third party intermediary) doesn't inflate the money supply (as seen on mainstreet), but repos by others "still count" towards M3.

Comment: @Fizz Prima facie that sounds like an untenable argument (for a variety of reasons)...but this is exactly what I was looking for with my original question - so thank you :) -- To hit intellectual "rock bottom" on arguments about the endogeneity of money, especially vis-a-vis the shadow banking "system."

Comment: @DavisClute: I was hoping to get/add some US perspective too, but according to Wikipedia "Since 2006, M3 is no longer published by the US central bank." That's not entirely accurate though, since I see the Fed [publishes](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/28) an "Institutional Money Funds" indicator now. I'd have to read up what it includes and wha it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

A repurchase agreement (“repo”) is used by investors to effectively borrow against their portfolio, which can then be used to finance other positions.

- For the “borrower,” it is the economic equivalent of a loan. A loan is a liability, and money is an asset.
- For the “lender” it is a short-term asset. It can be an asset in a money market fund, and money market funds are considered part of broad money supply measures. (In some jurisdictions, you can write a cheque against such a fund, I believe. Not possible where I live.) As such, has a relationship to money.

It should be noted that repos are included in M3 in the euro area, so they literally increase M3. [Link to ECB website.](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money_credit_banking/monetary_aggregates/html/index.en.html)

Comment: Hey, I understand repo - a close friend worked on Repo desk at JPM. My question is: Is there net "new" money being produced by a repo agreement? It bears striking resemblance to normal deposit banking at Commercial bank. If you put your money into a Commercial bank, the "new" money being produced is the deposit account. I.e. M1 just increased.

Comment: Put more clearly: Traditional regulated banking net adds to M1 (Its liability, your checking account, can be used in transactions). Repo is in M3. But, why? It's not because the liability is useful in transactions (like a checking acct). Is it because the collateral can be re-hypothecated?

Comment: The cash provided by the lender can be used in settlement of intraday liabilities (the intraday liability is replaced with an overnight one that can typically be rolled), and more generally for financing assets.

Comment: I understand that, and I 1000% understand what repo is, who uses it, its characteristics, etc. I'm just wondering if it creates NEW money in the system? (Like a commercial bank does - it creates M1 with checking accounts) -- It must create net new money, but what are its characteristics/nuances?

Comment: So it’s more about the whole chain— a money fund does a repo against, say, an MBS held by a nonbank. The MBS is composed of mortgage loans... that whole chain is functionally equivalent to deposit funding of a mortgage portfolio by a bank.

Comment: But it's not just maturity transformation, right? It must also create money...? (like its commercial counterparts do)

Comment: It does create money. People on one end of the chain received money in the form of mortgage loans. People on the other end hold money in the form of demandable shares in money market funds. It creates money just as the lending out of deposits does.

Comment: Repo “converts” a long-term bond (not considered money), into a money market instrument that can be used to back a money market fund (“broad money”). All else left equal, the broad money supply goes up.

Comment: So, while I'd agree with both of you, read Fizz's answer below: "...Consequently, the money supply is not expanded at the macroeconomic level..." --- This selected quote is in the bolder part of his answer. I'll ask him.

Comment: I updated the answer. It increases broad money, such as M3 in the euro area.

Comment: The question was and remains 'does it create money'?. Not does it convert one money into broad money. So none of this chitchat is relevant.

Comment: Not my downvote.... but have you found when the ECB changed their mind again? The info from my answer is from 2014, so it could well be out-of-date, given what you found. Or (more likely perhaps) they are including some repos but not others, and that's not reflected in the shorter summary you found? Actually, I'm going to ask that as a separate question, since this one is confusing enough with the idiosyncratic term "transaction-useful money", ahem.

Comment: @Frank - if the transaction raises M3, it “creates money”. It doesn’t create M1, but there’s a reason why broad monetary aggregates exist.

Comment: @Fizz - in any event, money market funds are in M3. Repos are held by money market funds.

Comment: I'm confused, you're basically saying that the ECB's M3 definition change made no difference? Or were they "double counting" these transactions before 2012? N.B. I've already asked https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/35792/is-there-a-clear-timeline-of-ecb-eurosystems-changes-to-the-defintion-of-m3-wi so you can "get credit" for answering.

Comment: @Fizz: money market fund liabilities are in M3 (in all countries, I believe). Repos are on the asset side of their balance sheets. Even if you don’t want to directly include repos, they show up indirectly.

Comment: As a final point, of course it's not simply MMF that does reverse repo. Temasek, Calpers, Berkshire, etc. Anyways, thank you all for this lively debate. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I will add this as answer:

Your comment "If you put your money into a Commercial bank, the "new" money being produced is the deposit account."

That's not how banks increase the money supply. They increase the money supply when they issue a loan. They do not require reserves to do this. Even in times when reserve requirement is 10%, the banks can create, say a million dollars in new deposit accounts *and then* put 10% of those in the central bank. More accurately the rate of interbank spending is so high that by the time they have to settle with the central bank what gets parked there is from a mix of sources. They can park securities instead as reserve collateral, I belive. This is how it works and I have a number of links to prove it. Here is rich source of references https://www.debtdeflation.com/blogs/2009/01/31/therovingcavaliersofcredit/ This myth that fractional reserve banking operations work by creating loans based on existing reserves, which are spent at another bank to create new deposits to create new loans, turning 10k into a million, is just that : a myth. Banks can issue as much new money as they deem healthy.

Someone putting 10Eur in a bank and getting deposit money in return isn't increasing the money supply. The bank would not spend its reserves, it would invest them, but today all banks need do is issue loans.

Repo is just a swap with an agreed future buyback. I don't see an analogy with the above debt creation process.

Comment: "as much new money as they deem healthy" and as capital requirement regulations allow them: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/27660/how-important-are-capital-requirements-for-controlling-broad-money-supply

Comment: @Fizz yep......

Comment: @Frank I feel like you & I are going to debate this ad naseum. I see your point, but pedagogically I think it gives the wrong intuition - it leaves people thinking there is so mystical process going on. I get that banks can create M1 (deposit accts) as much as they want...I get that...

Comment: @DavisClute in fact I really think you don't get it . How the hell does giving a bank your cash create money? Is that really what you think?

Comment: @Frank I think you should take a step back to cool down. I come here for fun, light-hearted intellectual banter. Not vitrol.

Comment: @Frank If you'd like, let's just go through the balance sheet of a REAL bank - JPM, Wells, Citi, etc. We're getting into distinctions so philosophically esoteric, that Jamie Dimon HIMSELF wouldn't even care. I feel like if we just analyzed a REAL balance sheet, it would help "orient" the conversation. I'm simply interested in pedagogical usefulness.

Comment: @DavisClute Sorry, Davis. Wrote that last night when nodding off and heavily under the influence. Didn't even remember I wrote it. Will get back to economics chat some time in the coming days, but yes, absolutely, I ordinarily also come here for the same light hearted intellectual banter. No idea what got into me. Demon alcohol.